# Rails 4 + using a themeforest template in project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i purchased a themeforest template (avant-clean-and-responsive-bootstrap-3-admin) that i would like to use in my rails project. i've google'd around trying to find an automatic way of getting this into my rails asset pipeline but haven't had much luck. i've also looked on stackoverflow and found similiar posts but looking for an updated answer. i've probably been spoiled by RubyGems so I've never had to manually install assets yet.

A) is there a ruby gem or some other automatic process to convert the assets
B) if its still a manual process, any tips / articles / etc. regarding Rails 4 would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think there is
2. ->

The best way I can answer this is to explain the process of how you're hoping this will work

You've got a series of CSS & HTML files which will work if you apply certain classes on the HTML page. The way you're hoping for this to work is for you to apply those CSS files to your asset pipeline, and somehow the content will populate the HTML files you've got

The problem here is that Rails does not know where to put the content into your HTML / CSS. Rails is a backend framework to create applications - it is only as intelligent as you make it

The best thing you can do is:

- Download the CSS & HTML files to your hard drive
- Put the CSS files into your `/assets/stylesheets` folder
- In your layout, take the overall layout of the theme & apply it
- For the views, use the CSS classes you've got from your CSS to create the styles you need

This might be void because of bootstrap, but the most beneficial way is normally the most labour-intensive :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick / detailed reply Rich. I kind of figured option B was going to be the route. In looking at some of the file / folder structures, the template has a few sub-folders. Should I keep the folder structure the same or cut all the files into the root of /assets/stylesheets?

Comment: You can keep it the same - you'll just have to structure your manifest files accordingly I think. That's where a gem would come in, but I can't think of any off the top of my head I'm afraid!